# Donde puedo poner una parte de un código en python el cual envia por correo una captura de una cámara de android usando opencv

Tags: python, opencv

tengo una duda con respecto a un código que hice en python, el código básicamente lo que busca es gracias a la librería opencv simular un tipo de cámara de seguridad con la cámara de un smartphone mediante la aplicación IPwebcam para android. Es decir, cuando el código se ejecuta en la computadora, se abre la cámara del android la cual se le ha añadido el IP en el código que muestro abajo (el cual siempre cambia cuando se vuelve a conectar a una nueva red). Además de mostrar la cámara de android, también muestra el movimiento mediante cuadros rojos y luego de detectar el movimiento envia una captura a un correo en especifico. Y aqui es donde tengo problemas, tengo el código de como hacer el envio por correo luego de detectar el movimiento pero no sé donde ponerlo en el código.

```
#incluir librerias
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sys import exit

display = True

def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
  d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)
  d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
  return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)

#marca de movimiento rectangulo
def marcar_zonas(frame_mov, frame_original):
  limites = cv2.threshold(frame_mov, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
  limites = cv2.dilate(limites, None, iterations=2)
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(limites.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  movimiento_detectado = False
  for c in contours:
#propiedades del rectangulo  
   if cv2.contourArea(c) < 800:
     continue
   (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
   cv2.rectangle(frame_original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
   movimiento_detectado = True

#captura de imagen
  if movimiento_detectado:
    cv2.rectangle(frame_original, (2,220), (185, 235), (0,0, 0), -1)
    cv2.imwrite("captura_imagen.jpg", frame_original)
  return frame_original

#inicio de camara
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.166.1.151:8080/video') #Aqui va el IP, el que puse es de ejemplo


#ventana de la camara
if display:
  win_marcas = "Movimiento Camara"
  cv2.namedWindow(win_marcas)

#color de detector
t_minus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#tamaño de la ventana
original = cv2.resize(cam.read()[1],(320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

#bucle
while True:

  imagen_delta = diffImg(cv2.resize(t_minus,(320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC), cv2.resize(t,(320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC), cv2.resize(t_plus,(320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
  imagen_zonas_marcadas = marcar_zonas(imagen_delta, original.copy())

  if display:
    cv2.imshow(win_marcas, imagen_zonas_marcadas)

  t_minus = t
  t = t_plus
  t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  original = cv2.resize(cam.read()[1],(320,240), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

  #tecla de cierre del programa
  #presione x para cerrar
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
    break


cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Este es el código el cual envia por correo luego de enviar por correo

```
import smtplib, getpass, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.encoders import encode_base64

print("**** Enviar email con Gmail ****")
user = input("Cuenta de gmail: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

#Para las cabeceras del email
remitente = input("From, ejemplo: administrador <admin@gmail.com>: ")
destinatario = input("To, ejemplo: amigo <amigo@mail.com>: ")
asunto = input("Subject, Asunto del mensaje: ")
mensaje = input("Mensaje HTML: ")
archivo = input("Adjuntar archivo: ")

#Host y puerto SMTP de Gmail
gmail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#protocolo de cifrado de datos utilizado por gmail
gmail.starttls()

#Credenciales
gmail.login(user, password)

#muestra la depuración de la operacion de envío 1=true
gmail.set_debuglevel(1)

header = MIMEMultipart()
header['Subject'] = asunto
header['From'] = remitente
header['To'] = destinatario

mensaje = MIMEText(mensaje, 'html') #Content-type:text/html
header.attach(mensaje)

if (os.path.isfile(archivo)):
 adjunto = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
 adjunto.set_payload(open(archivo, "rb").read())
 encode_base64(adjunto)
 adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(archivo))
 header.attach(adjunto)

#Enviar email
gmail.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, header.as_string())

#Cerrar la conexión SMTP
gmail.quit()
```

Si pudieran ayudarme en esto se los agradecería, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira te dejo el codigo unificado tal como necesitas:

```
import cv2
import smtplib
import getpass
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.encoders import encode_base64
# "**** Enviar email con Gmail ****"
# inicio del envio
user = "Tucorreo@gmail.com"
password = "claveSecreta"
# Para las cabeceras del email
remitente = "From, ejemplo: administrador <admin@gsmail.com>: "
destinatario = "asd <destinatario@gmail.com>: "
asunto = "Subject, Asunto del mensaje: "
mensaje = "Mensaje HTML: "

# Host y puerto SMTP de Gmail
gmail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
# protocolo de cifrado de datos utilizado por gmail
gmail.starttls()
# Credenciales
gmail.login(user, password)
# muestra la depuración de la operacion de envío 1=true
gmail.set_debuglevel(1)
header = MIMEMultipart()
header['Subject'] = asunto
header['From'] = remitente
header['To'] = destinatario
mensaje = MIMEText(mensaje, 'html')  # Content-type:text/html
header.attach(mensaje)
display = True
def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
    d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)
    d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
    return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)

# marca de movimiento rectangulo
def marcar_zonas(frame_mov, frame_original):
    limites = cv2.threshold(frame_mov, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    limites = cv2.dilate(limites, None, iterations=2)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
        limites.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    movimiento_detectado = False
    for c in contours:
        # propiedades del rectangulo
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 800:
            continue
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame_original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
        movimiento_detectado = True

  # captura de imagen
    if movimiento_detectado:
        cv2.rectangle(frame_original, (2, 220), (185, 235), (0, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.imwrite("captura_imagen.jpg", frame_original)
        archivo = "captura_imagen.jpg"
        if (os.path.isfile(archivo)):
            adjunto = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            adjunto.set_payload(open(archivo, "rb").read())
            encode_base64(adjunto)
            adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                               'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(archivo))
            header.attach(adjunto)
        # Enviar email
            gmail.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, header.as_string())
        return frame_original

# inicio de camara
# Aqui va el IP, el que puse es de ejemplo
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# ventana de la camara
if display:
    win_marcas = "Movimiento Camara"
    cv2.namedWindow(win_marcas)

# color de detector
t_minus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# tamaño de la ventana
original = cv2.resize(cam.read()[1], (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)


# el bucle:
while True:
    imagen_delta = diffImg(cv2.resize(t_minus, (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC), cv2.resize(
            t, (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC), cv2.resize(t_plus, (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
    imagen_zonas_marcadas = marcar_zonas(imagen_delta, original.copy())

    if display:
        cv2.imshow(win_marcas, imagen_zonas_marcadas)

    t_minus = t
    t = t_plus
    t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    original = cv2.resize(
        cam.read()[1], (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # tecla de cierre del programa
    # presione x para cerrar
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        # Cerrar la conexión SMTP
        gmail.quit() 
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ya lo probé y funcionan bien, pero el proceso es lento y envía muchos correos ( cuando lo probe envió 94 correos en un minuto). Deberías usar un hilo diferente para separar cada cosa y deberías tambien poner alguna limitación en cuanto a la cantidad de correos que pueda enviar.

Buena suerte.